# Чем заменить класс String в PHP 7?

Tags: php, laravel, php7

Устанавливаю в проект laravel 5.1 админку sleeping-owl 2 (http://sleeping-owl.github.io/ru/Getting_Started/Model_Configuration.html)... Все данные занес в указанные файлы: composer.json, config/app.php.
Ввожу команду :

```
php artisan admin:install
```

И у меня выбрасывает ошибку :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved in      /var/www/projects/blog.laravel.com/vendor/sleeping-owl/admin/src/SleepingOwl/Admin/Columns/Column/String.php on line 3
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
Cannot use 'String' as class name as it is reserved
```

Нахожу этот файл в установленной папке с установленными файлами:

```
 <?php namespace SleepingOwl\Admin\Columns\Column;

     class String extends BaseColumn 
        {... }
```

"String" - подчеркнуто красной линией и указывает, что класс c именем int, bool, string запрещены в использовании в php 7 !!!!! И код может быть несовместимым....
Т.е. class String нужно заменитиь каким-то другим названием??? или sleeping-owl 2 нельзя тогда поставить на php 7. 
Помогите разобраться....

Я так понял, что версии не совпадают...... решил поставить самую новую версию...sleepingowl 4 (http://sleepingowladmin.ru/docs/)...
Так же внес изменения в файлы...Пакеты все поставились и распоковались...Ввожу команду:

```
php artisan sleepingowl:install
```

...выдает ошибку :

```
[ErrorException]                         
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Недействительный аргумент для foreach()...но уже нет ни указаний в каком файле и какой строке...... PHP 7.0 laravel 5.1 sleepingowl 4 у меня стоит....может в комплектации что-то не так????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На PHP 7.0 нужно поставить laravel 5.3 и подключитьь sleepingowl 4! В таком комплексе все ставится!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема совместимости с PHP7 исправлена почти год назад: [github: Совместимость с PHP 7](https://github.com/LaravelRUS/SleepingOwlAdmin/issues/1)

Класс тогда переименовали на `Text`.

Стоит обновить пакет.

Comment: я только недавно обновил php  до 7 версии, еще не ощутил все особенности....спасибо,буду пробовать

Comment: Обновить не php, а SleepingOwl

Comment: я php обновил неделю назад или 2 недели.....а с sleepingowl вот только начал разбираться